# Creating Wait message in Java For when thread finishes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, thread-safety, jdialog

In my program,  a user clicks a button which is supposed to access and unzip a file. Unfortunately , accessing and unziping the file takes a long time and I would like to create a message that says "please wait a minute". However, whenever I create the message in the jframe inside the button listener the JFrame is black and does not fill until the end (probably thread reasons) . I've also tried creating a JDialog however this stops the execution of the rest of the program until the user says ok which wait even more time. I've tried nonmodal JDialogs so far that has not worked. I could make another listener,however, I want my window to close when the file is retrieved.
Here's the code:

AttendanceDriver makes and retrieves the file
commented code includes some things  I've tried

Does anyone know any way to do this ?

```
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                dispose();

                    /*JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DaySelectDialog.this,
                            "Please Wait while we try to generate your report",
                            "Lakeside Attendance Report",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);*/

                    succeeded = true;
                    //dispose();

                /*try {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane("Hi..",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            op.setMessage("PLEase say something");
                            JDialog dialog = op.createDialog("Break");
                            dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                            dialog.setModal(false);

                           // dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                            dialog.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }*/



               /* Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){



                       // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
                    }
                });
                t.start();*/

                /*EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane("Hi..",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        JDialog dialog = op.createDialog("Break");
                        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                        dialog.setModal(false);
                        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                        dialog.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });*/




                 //JFrame way 

                 //   JFrame waitNote = new JFrame();
                  // JLabel waitText = new JLabel("Please Wait While we generate report");
                  // waitNote.add(waitText);
                    //waitNote.setText("hello");
                  // waitNote.setVisible(true);
               /* JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Hello","Empty?", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);
                dispose();*/
                   // parent.reconfig;

                      //run Actual Program
                 // TODO catch exception if file is not generated successfully then go back to day select
                      String[] arguments = new String[] {"123"};
                      AttendanceDriver.main(arguments);

                      //view txt file automaticly in Desktop
                      //added by Hans
                      //DaySelectDialog.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()
                      File attendancetxt = new File(AttendanceDriver.getReportName());
                      try {
                          Desktop.getDesktop().open(attendancetxt);
                      } catch (IOException en) {
                          en.printStackTrace();
                      }






                   /* JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DaySelectDialog.this,
                            "There has been an error creating the report.",
                            "Lakeside Attendance Report",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    // reset username and password
                    succeeded = false;*/


            }
        });
```

Comment: Swing isn't thread safe. Run the unzipping operation outside of the main thread instead.

Comment: You'll want to read: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Then use a SwingWorker to do your long-running task without freezing your Swing GUI.

Comment: However, I want the unzipping to be done when the user  presses the button onevent.

Comment: What's the issue with that